# Ajax pagination with php returning entire page instead of the paginated div

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a php website which has to display list of items on a page in paginated format.I achieved this using php but now I want to add ajax functionality to it.So I added this function to be called on the click of the page no in the paginated portion.
Ajax/Jquery function:(.paginate is the class for the page links)

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
$('.paginate').live('click', function(e)
{
    //alert("Here");
    e.preventDefault();
    var btnPage = $(this);
    //alert(btnPage.attr('href'));     /RealEstate/process.php?page=3&ipp=2&venue=Array $('#temp').load($(this).attr("href")+' #temp');
    var getUrl = btnPage.attr('href');
    //var dataLocality = { 'locality[]' : []};
    //alert(getUrl);
    $.ajax(
    {
       url:btnPage.attr('href'),
        success : function(resp)
        {
            // replace current results with new results.
            $('#project_section').html(resp);
        },
        error : function()
        {
            window.location.href = btnPage.attr('href');
        }
    });
 });
});
```

My paginate function is somewhat like this:

```
function paginate()
{
    if(!isset($this->default_ipp)) $this->default_ipp='2';
    if($_GET['ipp'] == 'All')
    {
        $this->num_pages = 1;

    }
    else
    {
        if(!is_numeric($this->items_per_page) OR $this->items_per_page <= 0) $this->items_per_page = $this->default_ipp;
        $this->num_pages = ceil($this->items_total/$this->items_per_page);
    }
    $this->current_page = (isset($_GET['page'])) ? (int) $_GET['page'] : 1 ; // must be numeric > 0
    $prev_page = $this->current_page-1;
    $next_page = $this->current_page+1;
    if($_GET)
    {
        $args = explode("&",$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
        foreach($args as $arg)
        {
            $keyval = explode("=",$arg);
            if($keyval[0] != "page" And $keyval[0] != "ipp") $this->querystring .= "&" . $arg;
        }
    }

    if($_POST)
    {
        foreach($_POST as $key=>$val)
        {
            if($key != "page" And $key != "ipp") $this->querystring .= "&$key=$val";
        }
    }
    if($this->num_pages > 4)
    {
        $this->return = ($this->current_page > 1 And $this->items_total >= 10) ? "<a class=\"paginate\" href=\"$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?page=$prev_page&ipp=$this->items_per_page$this->querystring\">&laquo; Previous</a> ":"<span class=\"inactive\" href=\"#\">&laquo; Previous</span> ";

        $this->start_range = $this->current_page - floor($this->mid_range/2);
        $this->end_range = $this->current_page + floor($this->mid_range/2);

        if($this->start_range <= 0)
        {
            $this->end_range += abs($this->start_range)+1;
            $this->start_range = 1;
        }
        if($this->end_range > $this->num_pages)
        {
            $this->start_range -= $this->end_range-$this->num_pages;
            $this->end_range = $this->num_pages;
        }
        $this->range = range($this->start_range,$this->end_range);

        for($i=1;$i<=$this->num_pages;$i++)
        {
            if($this->range[0] > 2 And $i == $this->range[0]) $this->return .= " ... ";
            // loop through all pages. if first, last, or in range, display
            if($i==1 Or $i==$this->num_pages Or in_array($i,$this->range))
            {
                $this->return .= ($i == $this->current_page And $_GET['page'] != 'All') ? "<a title=\"Go to page $i of $this->num_pages\" class=\"current\" href=\"#\">$i</a> ":"<a class=\"paginate\" title=\"Go to page $i of $this->num_pages\" href=\"$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?page=$i&ipp=$this->items_per_page$this->querystring\">$i</a> ";
            }
            if($this->range[$this->mid_range-1] < $this->num_pages-1 And $i == $this->range[$this->mid_range-1]) $this->return .= " ... ";
        }
        $this->return .= (($this->current_page < $this->num_pages And $this->items_total >= 10) And ($_GET['page'] != 'All') And $this->current_page > 0) ? "<a class=\"paginate\" href=\"$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?page=$next_page&ipp=$this->items_per_page$this->querystring\">Next &raquo;</a>\n":"<span class=\"inactive\" href=\"#\">&raquo; Next</span>\n";
        $this->return .= ($_GET['page'] == 'All') ? "<a class=\"current\" style=\"margin-left:10px\" href=\"#\">All</a> \n":"<a class=\"paginate\" style=\"margin-left:10px\" href=\"$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?page=1&ipp=All$this->querystring\">All</a> \n";
    }
    else
    {
        for($i=1;$i<=$this->num_pages;$i++)
        {
            $this->return .= ($i == $this->current_page) ? "<a class=\"current\" href=\"#\">$i</a> ":"<a class=\"paginate\" href=\"$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?page=$i&ipp=$this->items_per_page$this->querystring\">$i</a> ";
        }
        $this->return .= "<a class=\"paginate\" href=\"$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?page=1&ipp=All$this->querystring\">All</a> \n";
    }
    $this->low = ($this->current_page <= 0) ? 0:($this->current_page-1) * $this->items_per_page;
    if($this->current_page <= 0) $this->items_per_page = 0;
    $this->limit = ($_GET['ipp'] == 'All') ? "":" LIMIT $this->low,$this->items_per_page";
}
```

On the page where I want to display the paginated **div**,i am getting the **entire page** as response instead of the paginated **div**.I have separated the paginated div to a separate page and included it(added code below) on the display page,but not working.

```
<div id="project_section">
    <?php include_once("cityPropertySearchResults.php");?>        
</div>
```

Can someone throw some light over it?
**UPDATED:**
I found something similar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309197/prevent-entire-php-execution-on-ajax-request?rq=1)

This works for the links but now,all the js files go on loading again and again,recursively.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Could you try with the limitstart in the query.

Comment: @muthu I didn't get you!! Query isn't the problem here.I am getting all the records but when I click on the pagination link it gets the **entire** page back instead of only a **part** of the page.

Comment: use the bind instead of live It may helps you. Sorry for the misunderstanding

Comment: That's fine actually can't add everything as it would be too lengthy for everyone to figure out.Will try it out.

Answer (score 3):

First assign the limit start as 0 after the first page load increase the limit start values as the limit per page and pass that value through the ajax and in the query use that limit start (e.g SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 0,10;)

Comment: I found it !!A slightly different question,but the answer applies to my question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309197/prevent-entire-php-execution-on-ajax-request?rq=1

Comment: But now all the js files are loaded on each page no click,which affects the performance!!Can I have your say on this??Thanks for the help till now!